# Al simular herencia en javascript, por qué se utilizan call en el constructor, y no se instancia el prototipo de clase base

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Aprendiendo más acerca de clases y herencia, me encontré con este código, pero algunas secciones del **código me parecen confusas.**

- *Entiendo que tiene 2 constructores que son Document y Book, Document tiene 3 propiedades y un método en su prototipo, y Book tiene una propiedad que es topic.*

**Que no entiendo?**

- No entiendo porqué *llama* al `constructor` Document con `call` desde *Book*, sé que `call` es para llamar a una función **cambiandole el contexto y pasando parámetros**, parecido a `apply`(pero este es con array como parametro)
- No entiendo que hace en `Book.prototype = Object.create(Document.prototype)`, investigando leí que es para **heredar el prototipo** de `Document`, pero porque no mejor *instanciarlo*?, además probé yo mismo haciendo código y creo que sí lo hereda, pero para realmente estar seguro, quiero saber que realmente sucede.

```js
function Document(title, author, isPublished){
  
  this.title = title;
  this.autor = author;
  this.isPublished = isPublished;
  
}

Document.prototype.publish = function(){  
   this.isPublished = true;
};

// Herencia de clase

function Book(title, author, topic){
  Document.call(this, title, author, true);
  this.topic = topic;
}

Book.prototype = Object.create(Document.prototype);

/* Probando para ver si hereda el prototipo de Document */
var b = new Book();
b.publish();
console.log(b.isPublished);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primera pregunta

Cuando llamamos a una función con el operador `new` se crea un nuevo objeto accesible desde la referencia `this`, no obstante si llamamos a una función con `call` el objeto enviado en el primer parámetro será la referencia accesible por `this`. Si no se especifica objeto alguno para la referencia en `this`, entonces `this` sera el objeto `window` (en navegadores, en nodejs sería el objeto `global`)

```
function Foo()
{
    return this;
}
```

Si hacemos

```
console.log(Foo()) // window
console.log(new Foo()) // {}
```

Es totalmente equivalente a hacer

```
console.log(Foo.call(window)) // window
console.log(Foo.call({})) // {}
```

La única diferencia resultante, es que nosotros creamos el objeto, en lugar de delegarselo al operador `new`

[image: consola ejemplo 1]

> No entiendo porqué llama al constructor Document con call desde Book,
>   sé que call es para llamar a una función cambiandole el contexto y
>   pasando parámetros, parecido a apply(pero este es con array como
>   parametro).

Lo hace para poder aplicar el constructor `Document` al objeto referenciado por `this` en `Book` (ya sea con el operador new o sin él), en palabras de POO sería "Llamar al constructor padre" en Javascript sería "Aplicar Document al objeto referenciado en this"

Los nuevos en Javascript cometen el inocente error de codear algo como esto

```
function Book(...)
{
    this = new Document(...);
}
```

La lógica es: hacer que this, sea una nueva instancia de `Document`, y posterior a ello, trabajaríamos con dicho objeto para hacer nuevos cambios. El anterior razonamiento es totalmente válido, si no fuese por la problemática en que `this` es un atributo constante de solo lectura, y por ende no se puede cambiar su valor.

Como puedes ver, la problemática de `this` es la que obliga a usar `call` o bien copiar los atributos del nuevo objeto en el objeto referenciado por `this`, a través de `assign`

```
function Book(...)
{
    Object.assign(this, new Document(...))
}
```

El anterior código es válido semánticamente, y también lo permite el lenguaje, sin embargo no es la opción más óptima. Ya que se crea un nuevo objeto en la marcha, y se pierde tiempo de cómputo en copiar los atributos, por ello es que se utiliza `call`.

## Segunda pregunta

> No entiendo que hace en Book.prototype =
>   Object.create(Document.prototype), investigando leí que es para
>   heredar el prototipo de Document, pero porque no mejor instanciarlo?,
>   además probé yo mismo haciendo código y creo que sí lo hereda, pero
>   para realmente estar seguro, quiero saber que realmente sucede.

Eso se debe a que es la forma más habitual o bien "más correcta" de elaborar una cadena de prototipado, semánticamente (para la POO), ambos son correctos, no obstante, en la cadena prototipados nos toparíamos en que el prototipo de `Book` contiene en su cadena de prototipados a un objeto resultante de aplicar `Document`, lo cuál no es lo que realmente queremos... Nosotros queremos que `Book` contenga en su cadena de prototipados el prototipo de `Document`

Para verlo mejor

```
function Punto2D(x,y)
{
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
}

Punto2D.prototype = {
    setX: function(x){this.x = x},
    setY: function(y){this.y = y}
}

function Punto3D(x, y, z)
{
    Punto2D.call(this, x, y)
    this.z = z
}

Punto3D.prototype = new Punto2D()
```

Si nosotros hacemos lo anterior, nuestra cadena de prototipado contiene basura.

[image: basura en el prototipado]

La razón: la cadena de prototipados de Punto3D no contiene al prototipo de Punto2D, si no más bien a una instancia de él.

Si se cambiase la última línea por

```
Punto3D.prototype = Object.create(Punto2D.prototype)
```

La cadena de prototipos no contendría basura, ya que todo objeto es un prototipo, no una instancia de algún constructor concreto.

[image: prototipado sin basura]

Comment: En lo de la segunda pregunta, osea si lo instancio además del prototipo, tendré coordenadas X e Y de Punto2D como si fuese independiente a Punto3D ?

Comment: Sí, tendrás repetido las coordenadas `X` e `Y`, y en general cualquier miembro que cree `Punto2D`, no obstante no son independientes, puesto que si en la cadena de prototipados aparece un mismo miembro más de una vez, entonces se utilizará la primer referencia. Es decir, Las únicas `x` e `y` que se utilizarán serán las que se crean en el constructor de `Punto3D`, así que el funcionamiento es el mismo en ambos casos, la única diferencia radica que las segundas "X" e "Y" nunca se utilizan, y por ende, son basura, un uso innecesario de memoria.